# ClientAliveInterval is not closing the idle connection

Tags: ssh, openssh, system-administration

I have the task to close the idle ssh connection if they are idle for more than 5 minutes. I have tried setting these value on `sshd_config`

```
TCPKeepAlive no
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

But nothing seems to work the idle remains active and does not get lost even after 5 minutes of idle time.

Then I came across this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254707 they guys says

> These are not for user-idle circumstances, they are - as that man page
> excerpt notes - for unresponsive SSH clients.  The client will be
> unresponsive if the client program has frozen or the connection has
> been broken.  The client should not be unresponsive simply because the
> human user has stepped away from the keyboard: the ssh client will
> still receive packets sent from the server.

I can't even use `TMOUT` because there are ssh client scripts that do not run bash program.

How to achieve this?

Openssh version
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: Try setting `ClientAliveCountMax 1`.
https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveCountMax
> Setting a zero ClientAliveCountMax disables connection termination.

Comment: Tried that as well no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> close the idle ssh connection if they are idle for more than 5 minutes

This task is surprisingly difficult. **OpenSSH itself has no functionality to set a idle-timeout on shell commands**, probably for a good reason: killing "idle" shells itself is non-trivial:

- There's *multiple ways to define "idleness"*, e.g., no stdin, no stdout, no I/O activity whatsoever, no CPU consumption etc
- Even when a process is deemed "idle", it's difficult to kill the process *and all its child processes* that have possibly been created.

Given that, it's not surprising that there's only few solutions for killing idle shell sessions in general. Those that I could find with (little) research rely on background daemons that check the idle status of *all* processes running on a system (e.g., [doinkd/idled](https://sourceforge.net/projects/idled/), [idleout](https://sourceforge.net/projects/idleout/)).

One possible solution is to **check if any of those solutions can be adapted** to enforce an idle timeout on a specific shell session.

Another option is to **adapt the OpenSSH source code** to support your specific requirement. In principle, OpenSSH should be able to easily access console I/O activity and session duration, so assessing the "idle" property is probably relative easy. As for "killing" the shell and all involved children, running (and killing) the remote shell in a [PID namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html) is an effective option on Linux systems.

Both options a relatively complex -- so before pursuing them further, I'd further **check if there's existing solutions to enforce an idle timeout on a shell session**. Using them under OpenSSH will be straightforward.